# Upload files angular

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, ajax, ionic-framework

In my $scope.accept I'm trying to upload some files to my server, 
the script is working when I just do `<form id="mForm" action="http://.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` in my HTML.

But I want to stop the redirect, so I want to do it with ajax on my controller. When I run the same script in the controller side I get this error:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at subir .....**
At this line particularly: **var i = 0, len = filedata.files.length, img, reader, fil;**

```
function subir() {
    alert("ok");
var filedata = document.getElementsByName("file"),
        formdata = false;
if (document.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData();
}
var i = 0, len = filedata.files.length, img, reader, file;

for (; i < len; i++) {
    file = filedata.files[i];

    if (document.FileReader) {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    if (formdata) {
        formdata.append("file", file);
    }
}

if (formdata) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http:.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        data: {json: formdata},
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(res) {                    
                alert("success");
        },       
        error: function(res) {
                alert("error");
         }       
         });
        }
    };
```

This is part of the HTML:

```
         <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" onchange="openFile_1(event)" id="file_1" class="custom-file-input" name="file[]">
     <img id="srcImage1" height="0">                                    
     </span>
        <span class="item item-input">                  
     <input type="text" id="obs_1" placeholder="Observaciones" style="text-align:left;"/>       
     </span>
        <span class="item item-input">
     <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" onchange="openFile_2(event)" id="file_2" class="custom-file-input" name="file[]">
```

Comment: As you did not add 'multiple' to your input tag for multiple files, may be that is why length property is not accessible

Answer (score 0):

This line in your code returns an array of *all* the files that have been uploaded, even if it is only one file:

```
var filedata = document.getElementsByName("file")
```

Furthermore, when you try to access the property `files` of `filedata`, it returns undefined because the `files` property can only be obtained from an individual element in this array.

To fix it, try changing this line:

```
var i = 0, len = filedata.files.length, img, reader, file;
```

To this:

```
var i = 0, len = filedata[0].files.length, img, reader, file;
```

Additionally, you will need to change this line:

```
file = filedata.files[i];
```

To this:

```
file = filedata[0].files[i];
```

Or, if multiple files could be submitted, you could maybe even add a `for` loop that iterates through each file in `filedata`.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you're using AngularJS.

Here's one solution that you can try using angularjs

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files" file-model="myFile">
```

Here's `file-model` directive

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here's how your controller code looks like

```
$scope.myFile = null;
```

You get file details/file in `myFile` variable but it is a array so while you pass it to service, you should write separate service like following

```
 this.uploadFile = function(file) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file[0]); 
// file[0] if you're passing myFile directly from controller otherwise you can pass myFile[0] from there and pass just file here
            var d = $q.defer();
            $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': undefined
                }
              })
              .success(function(response) {
                d.resolve(response);
              })
              .error(function(response) {
                d.reject(response);
              });
             return d.promise;
        };
```

**EDIT:**

In your solution try this

```
var filedata = document.getElementsByName("file"),
     formdata = false;
     if (document.FormData) {
       formdata = new FormData();
     }
var i = 0, len = filedata.length, img, reader, file;
```

Your fileData is having all files so you don't need to do `.files`